# Express.js - How can I get the number of defined routes?

Tags: javascript, express

If I had defined a bunch of routes and wanted to get the total number of routes setup at any point, how would I do this?

I cannot put a counter inside each route as they are spread out though-out the application. I am looking to do this via the Express.js API. I have had a look though the documentation but was unable to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on Express version

**3.x**

```
console.log(app.routes.length);
```

**4.x**

```
console.log(app._router.stack.length);
```

Comment: I was using version 4.x and your answer is correct. Thank you.